# Assign character for names of vectors in R

Tags: r, vector, char, variable-assignment

would like to know how to assign a character element as the name of a vector in R.

e.g.

```
hk=0.55 
paste0("rr",hk)
[1] "rr0.55"
```

now I'd like to do

```
paste0("rr",hk)<-c(1:10)

Error in paste0("rr", scale) <- c(1:10) : 
Target of assignment expands to an object outside language
```

like leaving the vector so

```
> rr0.55<-c(1:10)
> rr0.55
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

????

thank you help

Comment: As joran points out the answer is to use `assign` and that has been answered here before.  With that said if you explain what you're actually trying to do we can probably give a better approach for dealing with your data.  Most likely the answer will be "Use a list" instead of taking the approach you are right now.

Answer (score 1):

Use `assign`:

```
assign(paste0("rr",hk), c(1:10))
```